# Eclipse Failed to start Android app in Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, emulation

I get the following output on Eclipse Console (Started with UAC on Win 7):
(Nothing on LogCAT)

```
[2011-07-01 18:13:42 - Test_Android_2_2] ------------------------------
[2011-07-01 18:13:42 - Test_Android_2_2] Android Launch!
[2011-07-01 18:13:42 - Test_Android_2_2] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-01 18:13:42 - Test_Android_2_2] Performing nx.Android.Test_Android_2_2Activity activity launch
[2011-07-01 18:13:44 - Test_Android_2_2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Test_AVD'
```

But still there is no trace of my application on the emulator. It just shows the regular menu items & API Demos & other stuff.

Am I missing something?

P.S.

-adb kill-server & adb start-server did not help.
-Launching SDK, adb & Emulator before Eclipse does not help. While launching the app Eclipse doesn't see the any `Currently Running Emulators` so I'm forced to start a new one.

Thanks,
Nisheeth Barthwal

Comment: Are you able to start other apps in the emulator?

Comment: Nope no other apps. Na-da. Not even Hello Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange as it may be. I went to LogCat console and noticed it had nothing. While people all over the net said to look for LogCat log.

That led me to thinking that maybe Eclipse wasn't able to talk to the adb.
Oddly enough my already running emulators wouldn't show up while Run/Debug-ing a new Project/Activity.

A somewhat of a adhoc approach, here's how I fixed it.
I opened the Devices View, which shows up the currently running emulators, mine wasn't there.
So I clicked on the little down-arrow & clicked on "Restart ADB" (or something like that). And presto! as the adb rebooted the Devices View listed my emulator (along with other stuff I didn't quite understand). Viewing the LogCat console showed the entire trace. And I could launch my app into the currently running emulator.

I had tried to restart adb numerous times through the console but it didn't made a difference. From Eclipse, it however did.

P.S. ADB still pesters by not listing the emulator & the same approach fixes it everytime. (Restart via Devices View)

Comment: This worked for me. I think I need to dig a little deeper though to find the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you haven't yet added the program.

Right click on your android project

select **run as**

select **android application**.

Comment: Well had that been the case the Console wouldn't be showing my Project name.